# The support of continuous function

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $\Bbb R$.

Prove that $supp(f)=$ the intersection of $\{F\subseteq\Bbb R| F$ is closed and $f(x)=0, x\notin F\}$.

I have no idea what is closed $F$. And why we need $f(x)=0$ since the definition of support is $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then suppose $f$ has two closed disjoint intervals which are the zeros of $f$. Thus the RHS is empty for this function, and by what you claimed, $supp(f) = \mathbb{R}$. which is incorrect I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $supp(f)=\overline{Z}$ with $Z=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}:f(z)\neq 0\rbrace$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of closed sets $C$ such that $Z\subseteq C$. On one hand, it is clear that $\overline{Z}\subseteq\overline{C}=C$ for all $C\in\mathcal{F}$ and thus, $supp(f)\subseteq\mathcal{F}$. On the other hand, if $z\notin supp(f)$, there is an open set $U$ containing $z$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in U$. So take $C=\mathbb{R}\setminus U\in\mathcal{F}$ and conclude that $\mathbb{R}\setminus supp(f)\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcap\mathcal{F}$. It follows that $\bigcap\mathcal{F}=supp(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by the definition of $supp$, we have that :

$$ supp(f) = \bar {A}, \text{where} \hspace{0.2cm}A = \{ x | f(x) \neq 0\}.$$

Where, by $\bar{A}$, we mean the closure of the set $A$, which is the intersection of all the closed sets having $A$ in themselves.

Now let us define $f$ as follows:

$$ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
          1-x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
          0   &  \text{if } 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
          x-2 &   \text{if } 2\leq x \\
          x+1 &   \text{if }  -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
          0   &   \text{if }  -2 \leq x \leq -1 \\
          -x-2 &   \text{if }   x \leq -2
          \end{cases}
 $$

For this function the $supp(f) = (-\infty , -2] \cup [-1,1] \cup [2 , \infty)$.
Which is neither the RHS nor the complement of RHS.